# why derivative of $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is the derivative of the inverse $\sin(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, trigonometry

Why can't we directly apply the chain rule here?

Why $\sin^{-1}x$ is not the same as $1/\sin(x)$?

Is it the general notation as inverse only for trig function?

Comment: The exponent $-1$ means *function inverse* not reciprocal. For instance, written this way we would have $\exp^{-1}(x) = \log(x)$. This notation is somewhat unfortunate; one often writes $\arcsin(x)$ to avoid this confusion.

Comment: A site search for, say, [`[notation] inverse sine`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnotation%5D+inverse+sine) yields a few results providing insights on the notational convention for representing inverses of functions with a "power" of $-1$. Try other searches, too. This question has been asked many, many times. You are not alone in your confusion.

Comment: There's also a (rather ambiguous) question about applying the chain rule.

Comment: I understand your confusion. $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is the inverse function of $\sin x$, and $\sin^{-1}(x)\ne(\sin(x))^{-1}$, but ... $\sin^2(x)=(\sin(x))^2\ne\sin(\sin x)$. This is just an inconsistency in the ways we write things. I don't know the history of it but it must have persisted for centuries.

Answer (score 1):

By the inverse function formula, we have
$$\arcsin'(x)=\frac1{\sin'(y)}, \quad\text{ where } \sin (y)=x.$$

If you want to apply the chain rule, you can apply it to
$$\bigl[\sin(\arcsin(x))\bigr]'=(x)'=1=\sin'(\arcsin(x))\cdot \arcsin'(x),$$
which proves  the above formula if $\sin'(y)\ne0$, taken for granted that $\arcsin(x)$ is differentiable.

Comment: May I know why this answer deserves the honour of a downvote?

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano!

Comment: Don't thank me...I pray even if I can't stand those who hate.

Comment: That comment gave me a good laugh :D

Answer (score 0):

The arcsine of $x$ is defined as the inverse sine function of $x$ when $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

When the sine of $y$ is equal to $x$:

$$\sin y = x \quad \tag{*}$$

Then the arcsine of $x$ is equal to the inverse sine function of $x$, which is equal to $y$:

$$\operatorname{arcsin} x = \sin^{-1} x = y$$

You can then use (*) and the chjain rule to investigate the derivative of $\operatorname{arcsin} x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \sin^{-1} = \arcsin x \neq  \frac{1}{\sin x}$$

However there exists a relation between the derivative of inverse and regular function,I wrote an answer about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3861823/688539)